# Excel Reference another sheet like a dictionary

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, cross-reference

On a sheet in my excel file, I have rows as shown in the following :

[image: Screenshot]

In a second sheet in the same excel file, I have a reference sort of like a dictionary that links each organization to an organization ID.

[image: Second Sheet]

I would like to fill column E in the first sheet with organization IDs, referencing the organization names in column A with the name-ID matchups on my second sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data is in a sheet called `Sheet2`, then the formula for cell `E2` in your first sheet would be:

```
=LOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A:A,Sheet2!B:B)
```

You can copy / paste that down as many rows as needed in column E.

You can read more about the `LOOKUP()` function [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lookup-function-446d94af-663b-451d-8251-369d5e3864cb).